# Disable select tag of inside td of tr based on id of check box using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having a table. Each row has select tag in its last td . Now based on check box value which is inside the another  td, I want to disable the select tag of only that row. Here is my code. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong

```
jQuery('#tableid tbody tr').each(function() { 

    jQuery(this).find('td:eq(5)') find('input[type="checkbox"][id="name1"]:checked).parent().next().next().find('select[name="roleselect"]').prop('disabled',true);
```

;;})

I'm posting from mobile by typing. Please ignore for any typo.

Comment: post your html code too @Syed

Comment: id="name1"  id should be unique

Comment: @jyothi, I'm constructing the table dynamically and there are no errors in console. All values are passing correctly

Comment: missing single quotes checked) after checked

Comment: Yes. Id is unique.

Comment: I informed already that I'm posting this using mobile. So plz ignore any typo. The actual code dosent have problems l

Comment: but in your code id="name1"  static .

Comment: Don't worry. I'm passing as dynamic. But only for understanding I have given a name

Comment: atleast post browser rendered html . otherwise we can't find where your madding mistake .

Comment: @jyothi I'm very sorry. I'm posting using mobile so I can't help in rendered html you can simply construct one static html and disable the select box based on requirement.

Comment: i can't imagine your html . how it would be .  so can you render any static html @Syed

Comment: Just take a table. Keep one select tag in 2nd td and two check boxes in one td. Give each unique id to one check box as name1 and name2. Click on that name1 then select option should be disabled. If name2 is selected then select option should be enabled. Hope I gave enough info.

Comment: i think one check box is enough . @syed

Comment: No. Two check boxes. Only one checkbox should  validate

Comment: if user two check box is checked what you do ? @Syed

Comment: I will check only one. Only one checkbox will be checked. I have done that validation already.

Comment: check my below answer . hope it will help you @syed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above comment i think this what you want achieve

```js
$('.checkbox').click(function() { 
 
    if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr('name')=='name1')
  {
 $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td:eq(1)').find('select[name="roleselect"]').prop('disabled',true);
  }
  else if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr('name')=='name2')
  {
 $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td:eq(1)').find('select[name="roleselect"]').prop('disabled',false);
   
  }
   else
   {
        $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td:eq(1)').find('select[name="roleselect"]').prop('disabled',true);
   
   }
   
 
 
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid" border="1px" >

<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>
   first td 
  </td>
  <td>
     <select name="roleselect" >
     <option>select</option>
     </select >
  </td>
  <td>third td</td>
  <td>fourth td</td>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="name1"  name="name1" >
   <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox" id="name2"  name="name2" >
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me check.